# Is it possible to use IMAP Query Terms in Javamail with GMail?

Tags: gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

I am trying to programmatically retrieve the Call Log messages that are backup up from my android phone by a little application called SMSBackup (highly recommended).

What I want to do is to be able to retrieve the call logs for a particular day. I have tried the following program, using JavaMail:

```
public List<CallLogEntry> getCallLog(String username, String password, Date date, TimeZone tz) {
    Store store = null;

    try {
        store = MailUtils.getGmailImapStore(username, password);
        Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
        if (folder == null)
            throw new Exception("No default folder");
        Folder inboxfolder = folder.getFolder("Call log");
        if (inboxfolder == null)
            throw new Exception("No INBOX");
        inboxfolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        Date fromMidnight = new Date(TimeUtils.fromMidnight(date.getTime(), tz));
        Date toMidnight = new Date(TimeUtils.toMidnight(date.getTime(), 0, tz));

        SentDateTerm fromTerm = new SentDateTerm(SentDateTerm.GT, fromMidnight);
        SentDateTerm toTerm = new SentDateTerm(SentDateTerm.LT, toMidnight);

        AndTerm searchTerms = new AndTerm(fromTerm, toTerm);
        Message[] msgs = inboxfolder.search(searchTerms);

        FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
        fp.add("Subject");
        fp.add("Content");
        fp.add("From");
        fp.add("SentDate");
        inboxfolder.fetch(msgs, fp);

        List<CallLogEntry> callLog = new ArrayList<CallLogEntry>();
        for (Message message : msgs) {
            CallLogEntry entry = new CallLogEntry();
            entry.subject = message.getSubject();
            entry.body = (String) message.getContent();
            callLog.add(entry);
        }

        inboxfolder.close(false);
        store.close();

        return callLog;
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (store != null)
                store.close();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

My two utility methods (fromMidnight / toMidnight):

```
public static final long fromMidnight(long time, TimeZone tz) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
    c.setTimeInMillis(time);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
    return c.getTimeInMillis();
}

public static final long toMidnight(long time, int nDays, TimeZone tz) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
    c.setTimeInMillis(time + nDays*MILLIS_IN_DAY);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
    return c.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

However, for some reason:

1. while eventually executing, it takes about 3 minutes to complete
2. I'm getting back the entire Call log, i.e. the entire content of the "Call Log" folder in my mailbox

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main thing that you're missing is that [the underlying IMAP `SEARCH` syntax supports only dates, not date-times](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4).  So your query will result in JavaMail issuing the command:

```
A001 SEARCH SENTBEFORE 16-JAN-2011 SENTSINCE 16-JAN-2011 ALL
```

(Put a breakpoint in `IMAPProtocol.issueSearch()` to see this.)

GMail appears to freak out on this query, which logically cannot match any messages.  Try switching your logic to a single term using `SentDateTerm.EQ` (which maps to `SENTON`) and it should work:

```
    SentDateTerm term = new SentDateTerm(SentDateTerm.EQ, date.getTime());
    Message[] msgs = inboxfolder.search(term);
```